# How to extract Parent element's tag in xml using python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, xml, dataframe, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

For example I have xml like this

```
 <managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/a" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="a">320ms</p>
          <p name="b">enabled</p>
          <p name="c">640ms</p>
          <p name="d">320ms</p>
          <p name="e">640ms</p>
          <p name="f">1280ms</p>
          <p name="g">6</p>
    </managedObject>
<managedObject class="new" distName="AL-76867/MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/b" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="h">320ms</p>
          <p name="i">enabled</p>
          <p name="j">640ms</p>
          <p name="k">320ms</p>
          <p name="l">640ms</p>
          <p name="a">1280ms</p>
          <p name="l">6</p>
    </managedObject>
<managedObject class="New" distName="MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/c" version="xL20A_1911_002" operation="open">
          <p name="a">320ms</p>
          <p name="p">enabled</p>
          <p name="q">640ms</p>
          <p name="r">320ms</p>
          <p name="s">640ms</p>
          <p name="t">1280ms</p>
          <p name="u">6</p>
    </managedObject>
```

And i want to extract distName from this if particular regex matched.
for example

```
pattern = re.compile('MB-\d/TB-\d/ST-\d/')

for i in Soup.find_all('managedObject',{'distName':pattern}):
```

if distName match with pattern extract distName
else
leave it.

I tried things but couldn't get through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems missing `+` signs after `\d` and `^` at the beginning. Also, if you use `html.parser`, the names of tags and attributes have to be in lowercase (`txt` is your XML snippet from question):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

pattern = re.compile(r'^MB-\d+/TB-\d+/ST-\d+/.*')

for i in soup.find_all('managedobject',{'distname':pattern}):
    print(i['distname'])
```

Prints:

```
MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/a
MB-85404/TB-85404/ST-4/c
```